# Xceed Datagrid ExportToExcel .xml/.xls/.xlsx format

Tags: c#, excel, xceed-datagrid, xceed

Is there a way to get the ExportToExcel function to use an .xls or .xlsx format instead of the .xml that it uses?  My customers aren't going to want to see a .xml file when they export to Excel.

Comment: Not finding a solution to this problem, I went with EPPlus and created my own datagrid exporter.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the [Excel XML Spreedsheet format](http://www.openwith.org/file-extensions/xlsx/883) an xlsx file. Simply change the extension of your output file from *.xml to *.xlsx, and try opening it in Excel.

Comment: No, it's not the same format.  I changed the output to .xlsx and it says, "Excel cannot open the file 'test.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid...'